# What is this arachnid?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I came across a photo on Wikipedia depicting an *Oreocereus celsianus* with what looks to me like some kind of harvestman on it. The photo was taken at the San Francisco Botanical Garden.  Can anyone identify the arachnid in the photo?  (See link below for full-size image.)

[image: Oreocereus celsianus with unidentified arachnid]
<sub>Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Oreocereus_celsianus_1.jpg</sub>

Comment: It sure looks like the harvestmen I saw growing up in northwest Missouri, but I never knew their exact names.

Comment: nice photograph......it looks like harvestmen...but what is that thing it sits on ?

Answer (score 1):

The latin name for this animal is [Leiobunum rotundum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiobunum_rotundum) and Nelima fuscifrons, order Opiliones.

examples:
[link](http://fauneflore06.voila.net/pages/arachnid/pisaure.htm#Faucheux)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wrong continent.

Comment: @augurar. This animal is spread elsewhere, the back pattern is identical, the description is identical. I did not find any argument against this match, actually.

Comment: Several other *Leiobunum* species also have this pattern, see e.g. some of the photos on http://www.bio.sdsu.edu/pub/spiders/OPIL/.  But I think you have found the correct genus.  It probably would not be possible to identify the exact species without examining some microscopic characteristics.